# How can i show my microposts and articles order by created_time in one page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The routes.rb

```
root :to => 'articles#index'
```

Micropost model:

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 100 }
end
```

Article model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :title

  validates :title, :presence => true,
                :length => { :minimum => 2 }  
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And the index define_method of articles_controller.rb

```
def index
  @articles = Article.paginate(:page => params[:page], 
                       :per_page => 5,
                       :order => 'created_at DESC')


  respond_to do |format|
    format.html 
    format.json { render json: @articles }
  end
end
```

While i don't how to write my articles_controller#index and the index view.

Comment: Where are those Microposts? The Article model would be helpful.

Comment: I know article model is helpful, while micropost is anthoer model. It's similar with article,but different, it only has short content.

Comment: So please edit you quesion and put inside the following: **1.** The view that gets rendered, **2.** Article model, **3.** Micropost model, **4.** ArticlesController (is already in your question).

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I update my question just now and hope you can help me.

Comment: Thank you. That looks better and worth at the same time :-D .. So the big question is: HOW do you know which micropost belongs to which article? I really have expected something like `belongs_to :article` in the micropost model, but there isn't. So how is this relationship established?

Comment: No, microposts isn't belongs_to article, It belongs_to user. That is, user has_many articles and microposts. So there have no direct relationship between article and micropost. Hope you will get what i mean and thank you again for your patience.

Comment: So you want all Articles and all Microposts of one user on a single page?

Comment: I want all articles and all microposts of all users on one page. It's a copy of Twitter and i add a new function-create article.

Comment: okay, so you will have three loops: one outer loop, which goes through all users. and inside this loop you will have two loops: one for all articles of this user and one for all microposts of this user. <- these loops will be in your view. in your controller you will have a single object for users, which you'll use in your view.

Comment: That may work, but all those articles and microposts will order_by user_id, right? How to order_by created_time?

Comment: thats also possible, no problem. so you would have to combine microposts and articles in a single model. so there are just 4 attributes, right? user_id, content, created_at and title. title only for articles, but not for microposts?

Answer (score 0):

What's exactly the question?

If you want all Articles on a single page, simply don't use paginate, instead:

```
Article.all
```

If you want all Articles ordered by created_at timestamp in descending order:

```
Article.order("created_at DESC")
```

Or did you want a second page with different ordering? Then I would create a new route which takes a parameter to tell the action which ordering you want. And then inside controller:

```
if(params[:order_by_created_time])
  # ...
else
  # ... 
end

respond_to do |format|
  # ...
end
```

---

**If your view is already working** (and displaying the microposts):

```
def index
  @articles = Article.order("created_at DESC")

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html 
    format.json { render json: @articles }
  end
end
```

Comment: I am sorry, i copy the wrong code. And i rewrite it just now. What i want is to show all articles and all microposts on a single page

Answer (score 0):

Given your code works you should be able to simply change `updated_at` to `created_at`

```
def index
  @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], 
                       :per_page => 5,
                       :order => 'created_at DESC')

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html 
    format.json { render json: @posts }
  end
end
```

Comment: Oh, i don't mean that. I want show all my articles and microposts on my index page